# How does nokogiri slop mode handle dash separated elements?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have this xml

```
<league xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/basketball/schedule-v2.0.xsd" id="4353138d-4c22-4396-95d8-5f587d2df25c" name="NBA" alias="NBA">
  <season-schedule id="eb322501-7291-457b-9bbb-b4106ecf9564" year="2014" type="PRE">
    <games>
...
```

How can I access the content of 'season-schedule'

So far I have tried these without any success:

```
doc2.html.body.league.seasonschedule
NoMethodError: undefined method `seasonschedule' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x007faddf5ce2b8>
from /Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@dime/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/decorators/slop.rb:30:in `method_missing'
[13] pry(main)> doc2.html.body.league.season_schedule
NoMethodError: undefined method `season_schedule' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x007faddf5ce2b8>
from /Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@dime/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/decorators/slop.rb:30:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems there is no nicer way than:

```
doc2.html.body.league.send('season-schedule')
```

Also please read the comments to the Slope section in [Nokogiri docs](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html). Those are

1. Don’t use this.
2. This may or may not be a backhanded compliment.
3. No, really, don’t use this. If you use it, don’t report bugs.
4. You’ve been warned!

Comment: `:season-schedule` won’t work, you need `:"season-schedule"` or just `"season-schedule"` to avoid `-` being interpreted as a minus.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is, since this works:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<league xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/basketball/schedule-v2.0.xsd" id="4353138d-4c22-4396-95d8-5f587d2df25c" name="NBA" alias="NBA">
  <season-schedule id="eb322501-7291-457b-9bbb-b4106ecf9564" year="2014" type="PRE">
    <games/>
  </season-schedule>
</league>
EOT

doc.at('season-schedule') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fefd20679d8 name="season-schedule" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fefd20678e8 name="id" value="eb322501-7291-457b-9bbb-b4106ecf9564">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fefd20678d4 name="year" value="2014">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fefd20678c0 name="type" value="PRE">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fefd2067014 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fefd2066f60 name="games">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fefd2066d94 "\n  ">]>
doc.at('season-schedule')['id'] # => "eb322501-7291-457b-9bbb-b4106ecf9564"
```